how to make one elastic index for each docker container
I'm tracking two docker container logs with one filebeat container. I send the log data to logstash where it can be filtered with grok and finally send to elasticsearch.
Currently I am creating one index for my filebeat but I want to create one index for each container my filebeat is tracking.
I tried this:
manage_template => false
index => "%{+YYYY.MM}-%{[container][name]}" 
action => "create"

in my output area where I send the already filtered data to elastic but it doesn't work, it creates no index
but when I write [agent][name] instead of [container][name] it works but then I have only one index for both of my containers
